# Why there is huge difference in response time from Iseries for performance test of same scenario in LR and Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am executing the same scenario in I-series machine with LR and Jmeter and capturing the response time/transaction count from I-series. When we see the response time from i series for execution from LR gives .01 where as Jmeter varies between .5 to .7

Can we achieve the same response time from Iseries machine for both JM and Lr execution of same scenario?

Comment: What mean I-series and LR? Can you submit some more information about you Jmeter test plan?

Comment: You need to compare apples to apples.